# Database; 2NF to 3NF questions about (Primary) Keys

Tags: sql, database, key, database-normalization, composite-primary-key

I'm currently learning about databases and 1NF, 2NF and 3NF. So far 1NF is easy, but I get confused going to 2NF and 3NF regaring Primary Keys and foreign keys.
I've read a lot of posts on here but I couldn't figure it out.

In these pictures is a mock up of the database and tables I want to create. I tried to make it as far as I could in 2NF and 3NF (both shown there)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS1Qp.jpg

Questions:

1. Could a foreign key be part of a Composite Primary Key like I did with 'member_number' & 'email_nr' for instance
2. in regards to question 1: This gives me a unique key, but is it possible for SQL to increment 1 column depending on the value of another column, both being used as part of a Composite Key? (example in picture -> member_number 1234 is coupled with email_nr 1 and 2 for unique ID's, but when I would add another email to the list, could it automatically create the couple 1234 & 3?)
3. Is there anything other then the Keys that I maybe did wrong?

Sorry if this looks a lot like questions previously asked/answered but I could not find an answer to this...

Comment: The answer to your first question is that foreign key can be a component of a primary key.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please for code questions give a [mre]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.